# Reopen Application from background mode

Tags: ios

Application is in background mode, i'm Using BLE Connectivity, i want to open camera with BLE Command, i have to Reopen my application from background mode, is there any way to do this?
Help Will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems :

1. As soon as your application gone into the background mode you will
   not receive any data from the your BLE device. So how do your application knows when to launch the camera .
2. For doing any operation you have to take your application in foreground .Then you can do any operations in foreground event of app delegate . There is no way to take application foreground automatically .

Comment: Thanks for Reply, currently i'm able to have BLE Commands while Application on Background mode, and yes you are right about take application on foreground, i have to take application on foreground automatically but not able to do that have to find some way for that.
Thanks For your reply that's help me a lot.